# Rails - Facebook Omniauth - undefined local variable or method `“omniauth' for #<Users::OmniauthCallbacksController:0x00000000021e30>

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I just installed the facebook omniauth to be used with the devise and followed the setting up process but encountered with the **undefined local variable or method `“omniauth'** when trying to signin with facebook account (this happens after authorizing the app on facebook)

The config of the omniauth was already placed on the devise.rb

```
Started GET "/users/auth/facebook" for ::1 at 2021-02-07 18:26:19 +0700
I, [2021-02-07T18:26:19.757906 #344142]  INFO -- omniauth: (facebook) Request phase initiated.
Started GET "/users/auth/facebook" for ::1 at 2021-02-07 18:26:20 +0700
I, [2021-02-07T18:26:20.451094 #344142]  INFO -- omniauth: (facebook) Request phase initiated.
Started GET "/users/auth/facebook/callback?code=xxxx" for ::1 at 2021-02-07 18:26:21 +0700
I, [2021-02-07T18:26:21.060527 #344142]  INFO -- omniauth: (facebook) Callback phase initiated.
Processing by Users::OmniauthCallbacksController#facebook as HTML
  Parameters: {"code"=>"xxxx", "state"=>"xxxx"}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 25ms (Allocations: 4188)


  
NameError (undefined local variable or method `“omniauth' for #<Users::OmniauthCallbacksController:0x000000000226f0>):
```

```
class Users::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
  def facebook
    @user = User.from_omniauth(request.env[“omniauth.auth”])
    if @user.persisted?
      sign_in_and_redirect @user, event: :authentication
      set_flash_message(:notice, :success, kind: “Facebook”) if is_navigational_format?
    else
      session[“devise.facebook_data”] = request.env[“omniauth.auth”]
      redirect_to new_user_registration_url
    end
  end

  def failure
    redirect_to root_path
  end
end
```

Appreaciate your help

Comment: Please paste the error backtrace with your question

Comment: Sorry sir I just added it

Comment: It says the error is in omniauth_callbacks_controller facebook action, can you paste omniauth_callbacks_controller code here

Comment: Sorry for late reply sir but I still cant figure it out

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this code was written in an editor that wasn't meant for code, but somehow your quotes aren't the standard "programming" quotes. Replace all occurrences of `“` and `”` with `"`.

In `“omniauth.auth”` ruby thinks you're accessing the `auth”` property of an `“omniauth` object that doesn't exist.

Comment: Yes, I also checked or irb console by just pasting this `“omniauth.auth”`. its quote issue

Comment: Thank you you two and it works fine now sorry for my recklessness